# Using two IDEs for the same project

Tags: asp.net, git, vue.js, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2019

I'm working on a ASP.NET WebAPI with VUE.js Frontend (and desktop Client as well).
The thing is, I really like VSCode for Frontend stuff, and it's also configured perfectly for Vue.js and my personal Preferences. The same thing applies to .NET and C# but in VS2019.

Is it a big deal if I work on the same project from 2 IDEs? Or is there a better way to go about it without loosing Git-support (not separating into 2 Files)?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with using the editor of your choice to work on a project.  It's a best practice to let contributors to a project use whatever editor they like, and to specify project requirements (such as coding standards and linting tools) in an editor-agnostic way.  This usually includes not checking in files that are specific to an editor.

So it's fine if you prefer to use two different editors.  You've articulated a good reason, and ultimately, pure preference is a fine reason as well.  I've worked with many capable people who have used a variety of editors, and all have done great things with their preferred tool.  You surely can, too.